# How to output < inside Text component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

Like this: `<Text> Math inequality: 3 < 2x </Text>`

How do I escape such characters so that JSX doesn't think it's a part of the component syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some testing, I found out that @stackdave's answer does not work. I don't know if it works on other versions of RN, but on react-native@0.51.0, I got the following error: `Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function`.

Your best option (safest/better syntax highlighting wise) is to do it like so:

```
<Text>2 {'>'} 1</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easily using the following manner:

```
let localizableString = 'Math inequality: 3 < 2x' //It is better to separate string literals from code for easier localization.
```

And then in your Component's file:

```
<Text {...textProps}>{localizableString}</Text>
```